# How to resize a canvas element on mouseover

Tags: html, canvas, dom-events, mouseover

I want to resize and slowly growing size canvas element (like a arc) on the mouseover event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouseover on the canvas itself? Just add an event listener and redraw the scene the way you want:

```
// Every time the mouse comes over the canvas the radius increases.
// you could even add a timer so that every time the mouse stays over
// the canvas the radius continues to increase constantly
can.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    radius += 10;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width, can.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(150, 150, radius, 0, Math.PI*.8, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dAQdL/

mouseover an "object" drawn on the canvas? You're gonna have to [add object persistence and detection to the canvas](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful).